# Why does .mouseOut() fire when hovering over text inside the mouseOut target?

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-events, mouseout

For example, if I do `$('div#something').mouseout(function(){});` then the function will fire when I hover on text that is inside the #something div instead of when I leave the div.

I want it to fire only when I leave the div, not when I hover over text inside the div.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mouseout fires whenever the mouse cursor leaves an element, even if "leaving" means it is entering a child element (which the text would be - at least on some browsers).

You may want to use "mouseleave" instead.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 1):

mouseOut fires when the mouse leaves an element - and that includes when it moves onto its child elements. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/kZcCr/